# Is there any way to declare and increment a variable inside ng-repeat of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat functionality of angular js

```html
<th ng-repeat="x in data.items[0].bf_val " >
  <div style="width: 70px" > BF Score</div>
   </th>
```

Now instead of just BF Score . For every row I want a number before it . Like first row should read (1st BF Score) , second row as  (2nd BF Score) and so on . can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would use a custom filter and the `$index` iteration var *(available in ng-repeat)*.** It should provide the formatting you need. Here's one way:

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/5a8a684502b76a2c21121694cfb4f644)

*sample output:*

[image: Ordinal Screenshot]

```
<div ng-app="ordinalApp">
  <section ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items"> 
          {{ ($index + 1) | ordinal }} BF Score
        </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module("ordinalApp", []);
// what ur looking for 
//found here: http: //forums.shopify.com/categories/2/posts/29259

app.filter('ordinal', function($filter) {
  var suffixes = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
  return function(n) {
    var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
      v = n % 100;
    return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
  };
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    bf_val: 1,
    bf_score: 30
  }, {
    bf_val: 2,
    bf_score: 40
  }, {
    bf_val: 3,
    bf_score: 50
  }, {
    bf_val: 4,
    bf_score: 60
  }];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $index and append it

```
<th ng-repeat="x in data.items[0].bf_val " >
        <div style="width: 70px" >{{$index+1}}  BF Score</div>
</th>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/NFNvc/772/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<th ng-repeat="x in data.items[0].bf_val track by $index" >
    <div style="width: 70px" > {{$index + 1}} BF Score</div>
</th>
```

if you want to have 2nd, 3rd you mat have to add the logic in there